# how to include header files in other src folder

Tags: c++, compilation

I have a c++ project having two src folders. Source file in folder 1 may need to include header file in src folder 2. Is it possible? or how should I write my Makefiles? thanks

Comment: -I parameter to compiler lets you specify include paths.

Comment: HI , i have a dir include and src which contains the header files and .c files respectively. I am getting error when i try to compile with -I option. 
gcc -c -I ./../include tree.c , as tree.c also include stack.h, it is not picking up stack.h

Comment: Related: [c - Including a header file from another directory - Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7581408/including-a-header-file-from-another-directory) (includes some more discussion about <> / """

Answer (score 35, accepted):

Depending on how closely the two folders are related (eg, if they're the same project), then it can be as easy as:

```
#include "../otherfolder/header.h"
```

If they're separate projects, then it's customary to simply add the other project's header directory to your project's header search path, and include the header like this:

```
#include <header.h>
```

(In practice, the brackets/quotes don't matter, but it helps keep external vs. internal header imports separate)

Comment: I'm getting `unresolved external symbol` for any class/method. I also want to do it like this with **cpp** & **h** files in a solution directory, but utilizing "Include Directories" and "Source Directories" seems to be not enough. Any idea?

Comment: Thank you, imports with quotes are pretty straightforward

Answer (score 3):

Considering you have src1 and src2 folders in same folder.
You have 2 solutions for this:

1 - #include "../src2/header.h"

2 - Add in your project at additional include directories src2 and use normal #include