# Including a header file from another directory

Tags: c, compiler-errors, include, c-preprocessor

I have a main directory `A` with two sub directories `B` and `C`.

Directory `B` contains a header file `structures.c`:

```
#ifndef __STRUCTURES_H
#define __STRUCTURES_H
typedef struct __stud_ent__
{
    char name[20];
    int roll_num;
}stud;
#endif
```

Directory `C` contains `main.c` code:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include <structures.h>
int main()
{
    stud *value;
    value = malloc(sizeof(stud));
    free (value);
    printf("working \n");
    return 0;
}
```

But I get an error:

```
main.c:3:24: error: structures.h: No such file or directory
main.c: In function ‘main’:
main.c:6: error: ‘stud’ undeclared (first use in this function)
main.c:6: error: (Each undeclared identifier is reported only once
main.c:6: error: for each function it appears in.)
main.c:6: error: ‘value’ undeclared (first use in this function)
```

What is the correct way to include the `structures.h` file into `main.c`?

Comment: What is the compiler that you are using? For gcc you should take a look at the -I flag (see the manual page). For other compilers check out the documentation.

Answer (score 68, accepted):

When referencing to header files *relative* to your c file you should use `#include "path/to/header.h"`

The form `#include <someheader.h>` is only used for internal headers or for explicitly added directories (in gcc with the `-I` option).

Comment: Please note that this is -- in theory -- platform/compiler specific. "The named source file is searched for in an implementation-defined manner." (ISO/IEC 9899 on '#include "file"')

Answer (score 36):

write

```
#include "../b/structure.h"
```

in place of

```
#include <structures.h>
```

then go in directory in c & compile your main.c with

```
gcc main.c
```

Answer (score 12):

If you work on a Makefile project or simply run your code from command line, use

`gcc -IC main.c`

where `-I` option adds your `C` directory to the list of directories to be searched for header files, so you'll be able to use `#include "structures.h"`anywhere in your project.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use the command line argument then you can give `gcc -idirafter ../b/ main.c`

then you don't have to do any thing inside your program.

Answer (score -1):

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include "parent_directory/structures.h>
int main()
{
    stud *value;
    value = malloc(sizeof(stud));
    free (value);
    printf("working \n");
    return 0;
}
```

Replace your code with this and don't forget to replace `parent_directory` with the path of the folder in which your file is...
I don't know whether your file `structures.h` has `.h` extension or `.c` so please see to it...