# Compilation Failed when trying to access header files from other directory

Tags: c++, c

below is the (sample) code structure

```
/src    
 /poreA
     - a1.h
     - a1.cpp    
 /poreB
     - b1.h
     - b1.cpp    
 /poreC
     - c1.h
     - c1.cpp
     - c2.h    
 /maincpp
     -communicate.h
     -communicate.cpp
     -network.h
     -network.cpp
     -mainfile.cpp
     -mainfile.h
```

Each folders (poreA,poreB,poreC) has its own make files

**c1.h**

```c
 #include "a1.h"  

//  struct definitions are defined here
```

**communicate.h**

```c
#include "../poreC/include/c1.h"

#ifndef POREC_H_

#define POREC_H_
```

**network.h**

```c
#include "communicate.h"
```

**mainfile.h**

```c
#include "network.h"
```

**mainfile.cpp**

```c
#include "mainfile.h"

#include "network.h"
```

**When I try to compile,**

```
$ gcc -c mainfile.cpp
```

I get error as

```
../../poreC/include/c1.h: fatal error: a1.h, no such file or directory
#include "a1.h"
```

I tried to understand the concept from similar posts but not able to solve this issue

[How to invoke function from external .c file in C?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21260735/how-to-invoke-function-from-external-c-file-in-c)

[Including a header file from another directory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7581408/including-a-header-file-from-another-directory/7581447)

Comment: Use the `gcc -I../path/to/include/` to add a new directory to the include search path. You can use as many `-I` as you need.

Answer (score 2):

When you have include files in multiple directories, you can tell gcc to look there with the `-I` flag:

```
$ # if in ./src..
$ g++ -IporeA -IporeB -IporeC -Imaincpp maincpp/mainfile.cpp
$ # if in ./src/maincpp...
$ g++ -I../poreA -I../poreB -I../poreC mainfile.cpp
```

Usually, small projects may have a single directory that might be called `inc` or `include`, where all headers go. That way, gcc would only need a single `-Iinc` flag instead of one for each directory.

Comment: Good write up, only other point is while a single `/inc` or `/include` path is convenient, most large projects and libraries will specify many separate `-I` location. (especially when using `pkg-config`), etc..

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin Thanks for the heads-up, I edited the answer to specifically point out small projects.

Comment: I am extremely sorry. It was a type error from my end. In fact, the header file c1.h calls a1.h and not c2.h. I edited the post. I tried both the approaches you had mentioned (from src and from src/maincpp), it is failing to compile #include "a1.h" which is defined inside c1.h

The error is
../poreC/include/c1.h:17:10: fatal error: a1.h: No such file or directory
 #include "a1.h"
          ^~~~~~~~~~
compilation terminated.