# linking an object file from another directory in gcc (using command prompt)

Tags: c, gcc, cmd, linker

Based on the hints I have got from this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7581408/including-a-header-file-from-another-directory) and the comments below
I have reached upto the following points:
Let's say I have a c file named `factorial.c` in `C:\Users\Bittu\OneDrive - Intel\Documents\My Documents\` directory

```
#include "factorial.h"
int fact(int num)
{
    if(num==1)
        return num;
    else
        return num*(fact(num-1));
}
```

and `factorial.h` in the same directory

```
int fact(int num);
```

and `Prog1.c` in `C:\Users\Bittu\OneDrive - Intel\Documents\My Documents\Programming\` directory

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include "factorial.h"
int main()
{
    int n;
    printf("Enter the no.:");
    scanf("%d",&n);
    printf("Factorial of %d = %d",n,fact(n));
    return 0;
}
```

Now, in order to compile `Prog1.c`:

```
Path: C:\Users\Bittu\OneDrive - Intel\Documents\My Documents\Programming\    
Command: gcc -c Prog1.c -I"C:\Users\Bittu\OneDrive - Intel\Documents\My Documents"
```

In order to compile `factorial.c`:

```
Path: C:\Users\Bittu\OneDrive - Intel\Documents\My Documents\    
    Command: gcc -c factorial.c
```

but, when I am trying to link `factorial.o` and `Prog1.o` to produce a final `Prog1.exe` file, I am facing errors.

```
Path: C:\Users\Bittu\OneDrive - Intel\Documents\My Documents\Programming\
Command:  gcc Prog1.o factorial.o -o Prog1 -L"C:\Users\Bittu\OneDrive - Intel\Documents\My Documents"
```

Error:

```
gcc: error: factorial.o: No such file or directory
```

one solution I found is using the complete path in `factorial.o`, i.e:

```
gcc Prog1.o "C:\Users\Bittu\OneDrive - Intel\Documents\My Documents\factorial.o" -o Prog1
```

or,

```
gcc Prog1.o .\..\factorial.o -o Prog1
```

But, this would not be a good solution, as we might have a c file (in `C:\Users\Bittu\OneDrive - Intel\Documents\My Documents\Programming\`) which is linking to many object files (present in `C:\Users\Bittu\OneDrive - Intel\Documents\My Documents\`) and as a result our executing command will become very long;
so is there any other solution to link object files from another directory?

Comment: The problems are with the spaces in the path. Either escape them or get rid of them in the actual path.

Comment: Or try taking them in double quotes

Comment: when I am executing `gcc -I"C:\Users\Bittu\OneDrive - Intel\Documents\My Documents\" factorial.o Prog1.o -o Prog1`, it is giving `gcc: fatal error: no input files
compilation terminated.`

Comment: You have to escape the \, too. Escape by adding another \ in front of them

Comment: when I am executing `gcc -I"C:\Users\Bittu\OneDrive - Intel\Documents\My Documents" factorial.o Prog1.o -o Prog1`, it is giving `gcc: error: factorial.o: No such file or directory`