# #include parent directory's file

Tags: c++, include, cmake

My folder structure is

```
libA
    x.h
    y.h
    algorithm/
        a.h
```

Now in `a.h` I have `#include "libA/x.h"` which is not working. Its searching for `algorithm/libA/x.h`. So should I use `#include "../x.h"` ? Is the second option a bad design ? currently libA is header only. but latter I may choose to compile it as a library

I am using cmake So can I or Should I add `libA` in my include path ?

### In short

some files in My algorithm directory needs to include definitions from its parent folder. I cannot make all functions templated because the types are obvious and it will be overdoing. 
So How should I design My project ?

Comment: "So should I use `#include "../x.h`" - Have you ***tried*** it?

Comment: What's your compilers (or more precisely preprocessors) opion about the path?

Comment: I am using gcc, but it should work with msvc as well. but I've never seen any of these compilers refusing `../` in `#include`

Comment: @DiproSen My answer was deleted without comment. I hope it was useful while it was there. In response to you comment, I would check whether the algoithms really depend on x and y, or rather than traits presented by those classes?

Comment: I could have made the functions in algorithm templated. but in some cases the type is obvious, making those functions templated will be overdoing. So I need to include. But I need to group the algorithm related files also

Comment: Special case of [c++ - how to include header files in other src folder - Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5134357/how-to-include-header-files-in-other-src-folder).

Answer (score 10):

Your solution with `#include "../x.h"` will work. Regarding whether this is bad design - probably it is; hard to tell without knowing more about your code.

Consider the fact that if you have many include paths, the compiler/preprocessor will look for `../x.h` is all of them, which may be unintended and too broad!

Suppose you have the following directory structure, and `Your_Code` is in a search path for include-files.

```
Unrelated_Directory/
    x.h - unrelated
    Your_Code/
        libA/
            x.h - the real one
            algorithm/
                a.h
```

This is dangerous. If you remove/rename your real `x.h`, the compiler will silently pick `Your_Code/../x.h`, which contains unrelated stuff - this can lead to cryptic error messages. Or even worse, this may be an old version, full of bugs!

Answer (score 2):

When making a library that I know I will use in other projects, I tend to use boost's inclucision style:

`#include <libA/x.h>`

This means that as long as the folder above "libA" (probably `/include`) is there, you can reference anything and everything beneath and with "libA". It also helps avoid collisions of similary-named inclusion files when you include things boost-style, because in your library and outside of your library's headers and other related code, you're always specifying the library you want to pull "x.h" from, e.g.

```
#include <SexyLib/x.h> // Two different x.h
#include <TheLibFarAway/x.h>  // but same name! I hope you also have Namespaces :D
```

This is only personal preference, but it seems to work out well for the libraries I'm developing and for `boost` as well. Hope that helps!

Comment: `#include <libA/x.h>` not working either. Its complaining No such files. Now If I add INCLUDE PATH libA users will need to do the same otherwise it will not compile

Comment: @DiproSen Well, think about it. You have to do the same with boost as well; you add the toplevel boost folder to your INCLUDE PATH, and then use `#include <boost/[whatever]>`. There's no way to avoid that unless the user adds your lib files to a fundamental folder that the compiler always searches (which most users usually don't do). So, just tell them to add that include directory; it's the best you can do.

Comment: But then no one can just copy paste the folder in a subdirectory and start using it.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using gcc, you can add -IPathTo/libA to add libA to the list of folders and then use #include "x.h"

Comment: Care to elaborate?

Comment: Included path to lib A explicitly in the gcc argument. Nothing much to elaborate.